# Organize DataFrame into columns by year and index by day-month - PYTHON - PANDAS

Tags: python, pandas, dataframe

I have a dataframe that I would like to plot by day and month, year on top of year. In order to do that I understand that I have to put the years into their own columns and index by day and month. I am not sure how to go at it.

Here is a sample data frame

```
    date    count
2012-11-12  219
2013-11-12  188
2014-11-12  215
2015-11-12  232
2012-11-13  210
2013-11-13  234
2014-11-13  220
2015-11-13  203
2012-11-14  224
2013-11-14  196
2014-11-14  213
2015-11-14  228
```

which should look something like this

```
day-month  2012 2013 2014 2015
11-12      219   188  215  232
11-13      210   234  220  203
11-14      224   196  213  228
```

Thanks

Answer (score 4):

Use [`DataFrame.pivot_table`](https://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/reference/api/pandas.DataFrame.pivot_table.html#pandas.DataFrame.pivot_table)

```
dates = pd.to_datetime(df['date'])
new_df = df.pivot_table(index=[dates.dt.month, dates.dt.day], 
                        columns=dates.dt.year, 
                        values='count')
new_df = (new_df.set_axis([f'{month}-{day}' for month, day in new_df.index])
                .rename_axis(index='month-day', columns=None)
              # .reset_index() # if you want column month-day 
         )
print(new_df)
```

**Output**

```
           2012  2013  2014  2015
month-day                        
11-12       219   188   215   232
11-13       210   234   220   203
11-14       224   196   213   228
```